# How to fight external include that always re-define it's stuff

Tags: c++, macros, assert

For example `assert.h`:

```
...
#ifdef NDEBUG

#define assert(_Expression)     ((void)0)

#else  /* NDEBUG */
...
```

This area isn't surrendered by `#ifdef, #define, #endif` or having `#pragma once`.

I want to define my own assert function, so I `#undef` it and creates it, but then when a file includes anything after that includes `assert.h` it overrides my assert function I made before that include...

For example:

```
#include "my_assert.hpp"
#include <iostream.h>
```

My `my_assert` will lose effect and use `assert.h`'s define.

Comment: Do not use the same macro names that the library uses. Use your own macro names. Problem solved.

Comment: use another name for your macro? e.g. `MY_SUPER_AWESOME_ASSERT()` ?

Comment: did you try something like `#ifdef assert(_Expression) // undef assert(_Expression) // define your_define?`

Comment: @strangeqargo That's what I did, but it will keep defining it's macro, after you include external file. (STD's and whatever)

Comment: You cannot use any of the identifiers defined by the language standard for your own purposes, unless the standard specifically allows it.

Comment: if really want to override `assert`, you can try include your override as a last file. Or define it right after `main(){...}` function. So it will be the last define which a preprocessor works on. It's a tricky question, but an interesting one.

Comment: @n.m. assert is not a reserved word in C++ (and in C either, I guess)

Comment: @strangeqargo 17.6.4.3.1/1 A translation unit that includes a standard library header shall not `#define` or `#undef` names declared in
any standard library header.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot you're right but it's not 'language defined'

Comment: @strangeqargo The phrase used was "defined by the language standard". That's the C++ standard, at the section cited by Revolver_Ocelot.